# Calling useState inside a function causes maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures

I am trying to set the data returned from firebase in `useState` variable but I got `maximum call stack size exceeded` error in console. However `console.log(items, "items");` returns the actual data from firebase,  Here is my code.

```
function Profile() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const { currentUser } = useAuthValue();

  const starCountRef = ref(db, "doctors");
  onValue(
    starCountRef,
    (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      if (data !== null) {
        setItems(data);
      }
    },
    {
      onlyOnce: true,
    }
  );
  console.log(items, "items");

}
```

Is there a way to use closure in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `onValue` in a `useEffect`, otherwise it gets called every time the component re-renders. Since it updates the state, it causes the component to re-render which is causing it loop infinitely.

```
useEffect(()=>{
  onValue(
    starCountRef,
    (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      if (data !== null) {
        setItems(data);
      }
    },
    {
      onlyOnce: true,
    })
},[])
```